# зачем программисту знать лямбда-исчисление?

Tags: информатика

Слышал, что для программиста очень важно понимать машину Тьюринга и лямбда-исчисление. Нашел несколько книжек, где описывается лямбда-исчисление. Скажите пожалуйста, эти знания реально могут пригодиться на практике? По мне, единственное что действительно полезно про машину Тьюринга - это Тьюринг полнота (что бы понимать, что на html не решишь вычислительных задач). С лямбда-исчислением сложнее - оно положено в основу функциональных языков программирования. И там есть такие важные концепции как анонимные функции, ФВП, каррирование.. Но неужели это нельзя объяснить простым языком? Что вот, ФВП - функция, которая может принимать в качестве аргумента функцию и возвращать тоже функции и т.д про другие концепции. В общем, вопрос скорее такой: Не являются ли все эти сложные формулы и книги про лямбда-исчисление уделом исключительно теоретиков? И если нет, то как могут быть применены на практике?

Comment: [например](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function)

Comment: все лямбда-исчисление знать не надо. на практике вам надо понимать что делает, например, такой код: `Func<int, int> f = v => v * 2; void Run(Func<int, int> f) { Console.WriteLine(f(2)); } Run(f);`

Comment: @Stack Это C#? А понять поможет изучение лямбда-исчисления как раз? Мне кажется что тут скорее вопрос синтаксиса конкретного языка, разве нет?

Comment: @Grundy, разве это не то что я говорю? Там на конкретных примерах и достаточно простым языком объясняют вещи, которые в книжках объясняются какими то страшными формулами

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров, вы просили _практическое применение_ - по ссылке как раз оно и есть

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров _"Это C#?"_ -- да. _"тут скорее вопрос синтаксиса конкретного языка, разве нет?"_ -- тоже самое можно сделать, например, на typescript/javascript, f#. надо просто понимать, что у функции может не быть имени, что функцию можно вернуть из функции и можно функцию передать как параметр в другую функцию.

Comment: @Grundy, может я конечно немного некорректно вопрос задал.. но что вы понимаете под практическим применением? То что можно написать функцию высшего порядка, анонимные функцию и т.д. на разных языках программирования - это понятно) У меня вопрос, помогают ли как то на практике все эти сложные формулы, термы и т.п. из лямбда-исчисления? Например, я пишу на Scheme небольшие программки вообще не задумываясь об этих формулах. Мне достаточно знать что для объявления анонимной функции надо написать лямбда, что ее можно передать в другую функции или вернуть как результат и т.д.

Comment: все зависит от задачи

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров _"Но неужели это нельзя объяснить простым языком?"_ -- можно, но это сложно. проще городить огороды из заумных терминов. как пример, посмотрите тут http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33871/discussion-on-question-by-evgeniy-miroshnichenko-----

Comment: Для практики вроде и не нужно. В общем случае для практики достаточно только понимания трансляции  виртуальных адресов в физические, прерываний и как работают машинные инструкции. А в  частности, например, для понимания, как работает \*nix достаточно понимать работу open,close,read,write,fork и exec.  Остальное выводится.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Лично я про машину Тьюринга и вообще конечные автоматы прочитал где то полгода назад. Оказалось, что некоторые мои лексичекие анализаторы работают по таким же принципам. Сейчас посмотрел лямбда-исчисления ... Как по мне, незнание этих вещей в теории, совершенно не мешает мне использовать их на практике :)

Comment: @Mike, а где это еще на практике применяется можете рассказать?) Это самое интересное для меня

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Для этого мне сначала надо въехать в это лямбда-исчисление. ломает. А по поводу Тьюринга и КА, да оно на каждом шагу, по мне так это просто способ научить молодых программистов основам пошаговых алгоритмов.

Comment: @Mike, понял, спасибо) Что такое КА подскажите пожалуйста?)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров КА = Конечный автомат. Мне когда один теоретик долго про них загонял я все никак не мог понять зачем это, если оно как бы само собой разумеется :)

Comment: @Mike, точно, конечный автомат, спасибо)